# Are there threaded SPARQL implementations?

Tags: rdf, sparql

We are building an iterative algorithm using a set of SPARQL queries for each iteration. This algorithm works great, but we're running into a CPU utilization issue. SPARQL engines like Fuseki are not truly multithreaded; they allow multiple simultaneous queries to be executed in multiple threads, but each individual query is single threaded. From looking at some Fuseki notes, I get the impression that Fuseki is not thread safe so this is not a trivial issue.

Since our algorithm is inherently serial in terms of the SPARQL queries, and we are interested in one run at a time, is there some SPARQL engine that can take advantage of, say, 32 cores?

Comment: Fuseki is thread safe by design.  If there are any problems, please submit a bug report.

Comment: @AndyS, from what I gather it's multithreaded in the sense that I can have multiple threads each with their own transaction. However, you cannot have the same transaction split among multiple threads. This http://jena.apache.org/documentation/tdb/tdb_transactions.html says that multithreaded access to the same transaction is limited to read-only (or one thread doing writes), hence my comment that it is not be thread safe (at least for what I want). I also note that the engine does NOT take advantage of multiple cores for a single query, which is what I'm looking for, hence my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there are, [BigData](http://www.systap.com/bigdata.htm) is a open source/commercial example of this.

My own project [dotNetRDF](http://www.dotnetrdf.org) also uses multi-threaded heavily, in my case I levarage the .Net PLINQ feature to parallelize joins, products, `FILTER` and `BIND` operations though they aren't always amenable to this.

On the note of Fuseki (*Disclaimer* I am a also involved in the Apache Jena project) as AndyS points out Fuseki itself is thread safe.  The issue is that the query engine (ARQ) is not designed to parallelize operations, some ideas about this have been discussed in the past but IMO it would involve a fairly significant rewrite.

Comment: I'll check out BigData. Our machine is a headless Linux box and I'd rather avoid having to figure out how to get Windows on it if I can avoid it, so I'll check out alternatives first. But it seems dotNetRDF would do what I need.

Comment: Depends on your scale, while dotNetRDF has a threaded engine it only scales to a few million triples in its current incarnation and is a non-persistent store (i.e. you have to load in the data every time).  BigData is likely the better option particularly for production scenarios

Answer (score 1):

The Urika engine developed and marketed by YarcData is highly multithreaded (up to several thousand simultaneous threads) and runs in very large memory.  Probably not suitable for a hobbyist budget though.  :)

Comment: Actually this question was from when we were working on an entry to the YarcData Challenge that they did a while ago, where we did get to use uRiKa. But we wanted something to A) play with for debugging and such and B) to compare uRiKa with a classical machine.

Comment: Oh, and uRiKa is an entire appliance, not just a piece of software. The machine uses ThreadStorm processors (descendent from the old XMTs if you're interested) which do their threading in a fundamentally different way from the way x86 chips operate. So even if you had the cash, you couldn't really use their engine on a standard machine.